# Jersey application not working on WebLogic

Tags: java, jersey, weblogic12c

I've a application that is working fine when I deploy it on a tomcat server but got not working if deployed on weblogic.
Tomcat verison is: 7.0.47
Weblogic version is: 12.2.1.2.0

There is a simple rest endpoint that returns a JSON:
http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/rest/configuration/test
Works fine on tomcat, on weblogic I get only the string "Not Found".

In the log files the only warings I found are the following:

```
<Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <MyApplication> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <24ad6e0e-7bbc-4781-b294-f546069677ec-00000007> <1511013418859> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>
<Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <MyApplication> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <24ad6e0e-7bbc-4781-b294-f546069677ec-00000007> <1511013418860> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>
<Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <MyApplication> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <24ad6e0e-7bbc-4781-b294-f546069677ec-00000007> <1511013418861> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>
```

The EndPoint:

```
@Path("/configuration")
@NoCache
public class ConfigurationResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getClientConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("test", "Test is running.");
        return Response.ok(map).build();
    }

    ...
}
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        register(ConfigurationResource.class);
    }
}
```

from the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sample.rest.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

weblogic.xml:

```
<weblogic-web-app>
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-application-packages>
          <package-name>javax.ws.rs</package-name>
          <package-name>javax.persistence</package-name>
          <package-name>org.apache.commons</package-name>
          <package-name>org.slf4j</package-name>
          <package-name>org.apache.commons.logging</package-name>
          </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

I already tried adding the annotation but without an effect.
Does have anybody any idea what I can do to get it working?

Comment: Not sure if you added `@ApplicationPath("/MyApplication")` to class `MyApplication `

Comment: @Optional: yes, that was what I tried (as I thought that is what was missing for weblogic) but that had no effect on the warnings and the functionality. annoying is that there are no other warnings/errors to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for that problem
after removing some lines form the weblogic.xml it worked:

weblogic.xml:

```
<weblogic-web-app>enter code here
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-application-packages>

          <package-name>org.apache.commons</package-name>
          <package-name>org.slf4j</package-name>
          <package-name>org.apache.commons.logging</package-name>
          </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

so I was removing:

```
          <package-name>javax.ws.rs</package-name>
          <package-name>javax.persistence</package-name>
```

this was the only thing.
Unfortunately, there was no real hint what was the actual problem as I was finding no error/warning entries in any log files.

It seems that these packages are not compatible with the ones that are provided by the weblogic ones.
I think it should also be checked if the according dependencies in the pom files are in scope 'provided'.